# Tax Class not being applied on Bundled Product Price Range

Tags: price, bundled-product, tax-class

I've set up my bundled products in Magento CE 1.9 using Dynamic Pricing. Prices are captured excluding tax, but are supposed to be displayed including tax - for simple products, this works as expects.

For Bundled Products it's a different story ... On the Product display page, the price correctly reflects tax, but when shown in (for example) the category grid, the price will always show excluding tax. So it will display something along the lines of `As low as: $10.00` instead of `As low as: $11.50`.

Does anybody have a clue why this is happening? Is there a setting that perhaps I missed that needs to be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to price indexer logic. Price indexer never calculates tax values, it is done only when you view a product page.

Since bundle does not have a right tax class id, the price will not be shown including tax on category page. On product page it already shows price calculated for current product selection, so you see the correct price.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ivan. For some reason though, after changing some the tax settings around (can't remember exactly what I did) and re-indexing my site, the tax was showing correctly.

Comment: In my case,when we apply reward point-100,it give discount-100 on Simple product.But when we apply reward point-100,it give discount-87 on Bundle product.What is issue?plz guide me.

Comment: It give discount(Excluding Tax).Why?